# How can I decrease a value from 1 to 0 over a given # of seconds but add a bias?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A value, $x$, which starts with a value of $1$ decreases to $0$ in a given number of seconds, $y$.
> A bias, $z$, which when equal to $1$ will make it so that after $y$ seconds have elapsed, $x$ is still equal to $1$.
> When the bias, $z$, is equal to $0$ it will make it so $x$ is equal to $0$ immediately.
> The bias, $z$, is a decimal with a range of $0$ to $1$.
> The value, $x$, is a decimal value with a range of $0$ to $1$.

How can I calculate the value of $x$ after a given number of seconds has elapsed while applying this bias?

For example, if the value $x$ starts at $1$ but reaches a value of $0$ after $10$ seconds, what is the value of $x$ after $5$ seconds if this bias number, $z$, was equal to $0.5$?

Comment: What is the effect of the bias $z$ when $z$ is between $0$ and $1$? Let $x(t)$ be the value of $x$ at time $t$. My interpretation is that: if $z=0$ then $x(t)$ jumps from $1$ to $0$ discontinuously at $t=0$; if $z=1$ then $x(t)$ jumps from $1$ to $0$ discontinuously at $t=y$. Then one example way to interpolate for $0<z<1$ is that $x(t)$ jumps from $1$ to $0$ discontinuously at $t=zy$. But the exact value of $x(zy)$, when $x(t)$ is discontinuous, might be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A value, $x$, which starts with a value of $1$ decreases to $0$ in a given number of seconds, $y$.
> A bias, $z$, which when equal to $1$ will make it so that after $y$ seconds have elapsed, $x$ is still equal to $1$.
> When the bias, $z$, is equal to $0$ it will make it so $x$ is equal to $0$ immediately.
> The bias, $z$, is a decimal with a range of $0$ to $1$.
> The value, $x$, is a decimal value with a range of $0$ to $1$.

- $x_t\in[0,1]$
- $x_0=1$
- $x_y=0$
- $z\in[0,1]$
- $z=1\implies x_y^{'}=1$
- $z=0\implies x_t^{'}=0$

Thus, this works: $$x_t^{'}:=z(1-x_t).$$